# PHP - generating a number of product feeds, maximum execution time error

Tags: php, execution-time, delayed-execution

I have an ecommerce site and am trying to generate product feeds for Googles merchant center.

It started out as one product feed for one country, one language and one currency, as we're growing we've a number for different feeds for numerous languages, different prices for different regions.

I had just been creating them manually but want to improve this so I've created a database of the combinations of countries languages and currencies that we want and took out the basic structure for generating it and put it in a function.

So now I have something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_feeds";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $country = $row['country'];
    $currency = $row['currency'];
    $language = $row['language'];

    generate_product_feeds($country,$currency,$language);
}
```

This kind of works fine. The issue is it will get through about two or three product feeds before I get a maximum execution time error.

Is there a way to stall the functions or do this in seperate requests so it will run properly.

Comment: what does `generate_product_feeds` do anyway? create an xml? maybe gather all data first, then create once

Comment: @ghost basically it generates an xml all of all my product information so it has a number of different queries to get all of the products, their options, the categories they're in, the pricing (which includes another query to get the exchange rate), which of our suppliers the product is coming from (this includes looking up shipping tables as different suppliers have different costs for shipping to different countries)

Comment: i think before you even go to do separate requests and restructure everything that's currently working on your system, you could first change the flow of your query first, maybe you're doing n+1 queries that slow down, if your database is normalized properly, you could have avoided this problem all together. its just too broad to make an assessment based on that code above, we don't even know how you generate your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being done by a cron job every night so I just changed my cron settings to every minute for an hour and did the original query based on the minutes, like so:

```
$params = [date('i')];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_feeds WHERE id=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
```

Obviously I'll have to change this if I get above 60 but the script can handle about 2 or 3 product feeds at a time so I can probably do it in multiples. And for my purposes I don't think it will even reach 60.